# Django: Mixing TransactionMiddleware and commit_on_success()

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, nested

I am a bit confused about nested Django Transactions.

*`TransactionMiddleware` is enabled and I am using `Django 1.5` with `Postgres 9.1`.*

What happens if I use  `transaction.commit_on_success()` in my code? A transaction is already open due to `TransactionMiddleware`.

1. Is everything inside this code block run in a new transaction? The outer transaction is left untouched and continued afterwards?
2. The outer transaction is committed, a new transaction is created and committed for the extra code block and a third transaction is started afterwards?
3. No new transaction is started and the current is committed after leaving the code block?

Here is my concrete issue:

```
  class User:
    [..]

  class Install:
    user = ForeignKey(User)

  install.user == user1 #given and True

  install.user = user2
  install.save()
  user1.delete()
```

When deleting an object Django deletes all objects with Foreign Keys that point to this object, so the install is deleted unintentionally.

Would wrapping `install.save()` in a `transaction.commit_on_success()` keep the install?

Comment: Hopefully it's using `SAVEPOINT`s internally. Check the PostgreSQL server error logs to see. To learn more about subtransactions/savepoints see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html

Comment: How does that help me with the question?

Comment: Because you'd be able to see what Django is actually doing on the database. And it's only tangentally useful; otherwise I'd post an answer not a comment.